# Javascript object property with variable name

Tags: javascript

I never thought I'd stumble in a problem like that but hey what do you know..

```
var prop = 'horses'

console.log({
    prop: 1
});
```

How can I have this produce an object with a property `horses` instead of `prop` and possibly have it done in a single line? Because I can think of a solution but what I'm really looking for is a one-liner.

Comment: truely one-liner: `var prop = "horses"; console.log((function(o,p){o[p]=1;return o;})({},prop));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bracketed notation:

```
var obj = {};
obj[prop] = 1;
console.log(obj);
```

In JavaScript, you can refer to a property either by dot notation and a literal name (`foo.bar`), or bracketed notation with a *string* name (`foo["bar"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, including (in your case) a variable reference.

> ...but what I'm really looking for is a one-liner.

There's no way to do that as part of an object initializer, though, you have to do it separately. If you want a one-liner, you'll need to do a function call, e.g.:

```
console.log(makeObj(prop, 1));
```

where `makeObj` is

```
function makeObj(propName, propValue) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[propName] = propValue;
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSON to create the object:

```
console.log(JSON.parse("{\"" + prop + "\":\"1\"}");
```

Comment: There's no need to fire up a JSON parser for this. Creative, though.